# Modifying a text file without reading into memory

Tags: linux, text-files

I was trying to figure out a way to modify a text file (specially deleting specific lines) without reading a big part of file into memory or rewriting the whole file. Here am talking about files larger than main memory about 15-50 Gigs.

P.S. I am using Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I figure as much when you added that it was a text file.

Comment: No, you are pretty much SOL.

Comment: This is just an idea but what if you memory-map the file or portions of it and use `memmove` & `memset` and the likes on the returned pointer? Should allow you to write and erase the file directly maybe?

Comment: @Brandon, what happens when a line is deleted (or added) and the size changes?  Can't do it.  At least not w/o inventing some incredibly convoluted scheme.

Comment: @Duck I see your point. I didn't think about the size changes.

Comment: Do delete a line you can overwrite it with blanks, if that is allowed by the syntax of your file. But if you need extra space in the middle of the file, then you will have to rewrite from that point on.

Comment: If this is a C++ question, please add C++-relevant code that shows what work you have tried so far, and what is not working within the C++ frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get around making a new file, so just bite the bullet and do it. Use `grep` with appropriate options and pipe the result to a second file:

```
$ grep -fv patternsToExcludeFromInput input > output
```

Another approach is to put patterns into, as examples, a hash table (Perl), a dictionary (Python), or an `unordered_map` (C++), and process each line of your input file to look for matches.

If there is no match, print the line to the standard output stream (which you can pipe to a regular file). Your memory usage will be limited mostly to the hash table and the line of input you are querying.

Comment: It again rewrites the whole file.

Comment: So long as `input` and `output` are different files, you should not be overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in "rw" mode and use fseek, fread, fwrite to read/write portions of it. You must pay attention of not overwriting the part you have not read yet. So to delete a line you read and write forward, to insert a line you read and write backward (starting from the end of file).

**example**

To remove the first 100 bytes from the beginning of your file you could do something like:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"rw");
size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 1024;
char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
size_t offset = 100;
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
size_t length = ftell(fp);
for (size_t i=0; i< (length-offset+BLOCK_SIZE-1) / BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) {
  fseek(fp,i*BLOCK_SIZE + offset,SEEK_SET);
  size_t count = fread(fp,buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK_SIZE);
  fseek(fp,i*BLOCK_SIZE,SEEK_SET);
  fwrite(fp,buffer,sizeof(char),count);
}
```

Comment: The `fseek()` function takes three arguments, and you are trying to use `fseek()` with both one and two arguments, so this code will not compile. But this code wouldn't work even if this function was used correctly, anyway, since `buffer` is uninitialized and you are probably just overwriting the file with garbage with the `fwrite()` call.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: Emanuelle said it was "somenthing like" pseudo-c-code.
buf is first read into and then written from, so it neednt´t be initialized.
You are right, that it won´t compile and do the job,
yet opening the file for "rw" and playing with fseek, ftell, fread and fwrite is a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: I added the second argument to fseek. Jakub has already answered the question about initialization of buffer, which is not an issue.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The standard `fseek()` function takes three arguments: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fseek.html

Answer (score 0):

If the file is way larger than memory, `sed` is your friend. It acts as a filter between your old file and a new file, and at the end, you just have to rename the new file to the old name. The syntax is a bit *strange* for newcomers, but it is really powerful, being able to select lines by number, by regexes,  or by range, and apply insertions, deletions or string substutions.